# Unity Terrain Looks weird

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

currently I have the problem that my terrain looks weird. Yesterday, everything was fine but today after baking a Lightmap everything white looks like in Picture 2 from near perspective.

What it should look like:

[image: How it should look like]

How it looks:

[image: How it looks (Picture 2)]

My light settings:

[image: My Light settings]

I hope sombody can help.

Comment: That looks like Z-fighting. Looks like you have two copies of your mesh in the scene, at the same location.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: I figured it out by myself. In the Rendering Settings under Depth Bias I just put a higher number in and now, it works